# Is this a front-end crash or something else is wrong?

Tags: crash

I am evaluating daily multiple notebooks (4) at the same time in order to perform a number of related computations. Been doing this for some time now and never have I encountered what I experienced today.

I am using v.12 as of lately and this is the first time I encounter *any* kind of problem with the front-end (or any kind of problem whatsoever-I even remember thinking to myself not many days ago that this iteration is really robust and feels more steady than previous versions).

Today, I returned to my station only to find that Mathematica had crashed (the application was closed) and there was a windows notification about an OpenGL [error](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3006).

I think that the computations were completed because before evaluating the last notebooks in the evaluation queue, the expected output files were already stored on my local drive. I didn't verify their integrity yet, though.

I suspect the crash-if it is related to Mathematica-must have something to do with the displaying of `Dataset` because the last couple of Notebook's evaluate and display Datasets.

So, essentially, my question is

**Has anybody experienced Mathematica v.12 crashing under Windows 8 with the error**

> "OpenGL “too many errors”"

**while evaluating multiple notebooks at the same time or has anybody experienced similar issues when evaluating cells with moderate Datasets in them?**

Any help is appreciated.

*PS*. I did the computations all over again, without adding the last two
notebooks in the evaluation queue and all went smoothly this time.

Comment: This seems like a bug and would be worth sending a report to WRI.

Comment: I'd ensure your graphics drivers are up to date, see if you can minimize the example, and then as Carl suggested, contact tech support. It sounds pretty machine-specific, so they might need to get a bit of diagnostic information from you.